# Can I create a list of TMP_Text variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a list of 7 TMP_Text variables so I can call them in a function using the list index .

Down below is a very simple example of what I would like to achieve.

```
public List<TMP_Text> ExampleTexts = new List<TMP_Text> {Text1, Text2, ... };

public void ExampleFunction(int i)
{
    ExampleTexts[i].text = i.ToString("0");
}
```

Or maybe this isn't possible and there is another way to dynamically call TMP_Text variables ?

Thank you for taking the time to help me

I already tried making a list of TMP_Text variables and calling onto them with the list index, didn't work.

Comment: well you cant do it as `List<TMP_Text> {Text1, Text2, ... ` but yes you can make list of tmp texts...

Answer (score 1):

I found it, need to declare

```
public TMP_Text[] TMPListName;
```

then assign the various textboxes through the unity UI